# when changing image-size td-size won't change

Tags: html, css

I have made a table with three columns, two with text and one with a picture. The table has 10 rows, so I gave the the cell with the picture a rowspan of 10. I am able to change the width of the picture, but for some odd reason the table-cell won't change it's width. The cell still have the width, the picture originally had.

I have tried setting the image to block, but that doesn't help with the td-width. I could give the td a class with a max-width, but I am looking for another solution.

[example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Jctej.jpg)

HTML

```
<table>
<thead>
<tr><th colspan="2">Attribute</th></tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
 <td>Stufe</td>
 <td>9</td>
 <td rowspan="10"><img src="#"></img></td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>Vitalität</td>
 <td>12</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>Zauberei</td>
 <td>10</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>Kondition</td>
 <td>11</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>Belastung</td>
 <td>15</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>Stärke</td>
 <td>13</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>Geschicklichkeit</td>
 <td>12</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>Intelligenz</td>
 <td>9</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>Glaube</td>
 <td>9</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>Glück</td>
 <td>7</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

CSS (nothing special)

```
table {
font-size:90%;
margin:1.5em auto;
padding:0 1em;
border-collapse:collapse;
text-align:center;}
article table thead {
background:#91414B;}
article table th, main article table td {
padding:0.25em 0.5em;}
table img {
display:block;
width:50%;}
table a {
text-decoration:underline;
color:#FFFFFF;}
table a:hover {
text-decoration:none;
color:#C6C6C6;}
```

Comment: The `td` that holds the image is wide because it has to go to the width of the first `tr` (which says "Attribute"). If you had posted code, I would have fixed this for you. Make the table have 4 columns so the last column can be empty and expand to the table's width.

Comment: Can you show us the code?

Comment: Edited the post and pasted some code. Tried your solution Wes, but adding a fourth column wont change the size of the "image-td", it's still the width of the original picture.

Comment: Tables aren't the preferred way to position HTML elements, except in emails.

Comment: Okay then, give me a hint what the prefered way is.

Comment: After some trail and error I found out that by setting the `width` of an `img` to 50% it does not refer to 50% of the original image size, but it does refer to the parents width. I could not find a way to affect the width of the `<td>`, so I've put the picture in a seperate `<div>`and set `display: inline-block;`.